# Connect to Oracle without tnsname.ora

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I need to connect to oracle from my .Net application.

I'm thinking of using [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html)

Is there a way to connect to Oracle without any dependency on the `tnsnames.ora` file? Reason I ask is because I'll have hundreds of different connections and I wouldnt want to be dependant on that file.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p19

Comment: data needs to be somewhere, what do you want to be dependent on?  If hardcoded in your .NET app, IT/DBAs can't update when needed.  If in a config file, whats the difference really? (a less standard location actually, imagine 20 such apps out there).  You can check out LDAP authentication maybe, this would be a good alternative imo.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authentication.htm

Comment: I want it to be on a table on the database. Have you ever had to maintain the tsnames.or file on a production clustered enviroment? Its a pain...

Comment: @Diego Hey, we all *love* tnsname.ora :-)

Comment: @Diego Not sure I understand, you want the TNS info in a table in the database?  So how do you get to the table to read it?

Comment: sory, my bad, I should have explained that the aplication runs on top of a SQL Server database. That's were the oracle info would be. Oracle is just a data source where I would be reading some data from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you use a connection string that contains the data of `tnsname.ora`.

---

Say your tnsname entry looks like this:

```
 YourTnsName =  
  (DESCRIPTION =  
    (ADDRESS_LIST =  
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = YourHost)(PORT = 1521))  
    )  
    (CONNECT_DATA =  
      (SID  = YourSid)  
    )  
  )
```

instead of using `YourTnsName` in the connection string, you can write it like this:

```
var constr = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder()
             {
                DataSource = @"(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = YourHost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID  = YourSid)))",
                UserID = "userid",
                Password = "password",
             }.ConnectionString;

using (var con = new OracleConnection(constr))
{ 
    ... 
}
```

hence no entry in `tnsname.ora` is needed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx says that `OracleConnection` is deprecated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party Oracle provider. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: @JPHellemons Using another Oracle provider won't make a difference. The connection string is the same.