# connecting oracle 10g enterprise with asp.net code gives error for tns 1

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm using this code to access the oracle db of remote server, but am unable to connect

```
OleDbConnection oCon = new OleDbConnection();
oCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=FAIMS_DEV;Password=FAIMS_DEV;Data source=FAIMSDEV;";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TAB", oCon);

//OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT COMP_CODE, CATEGORY_GRP_CODE, CATEGORY_CODE, BRIEF_DESC_ENG, SYSDATE, 'MIS_USER' FROM ICSPCT", oCon);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Your connection string looks like it is for MS Access.  If you are trying to connect to Oracle, you will need the Oracle Data Adapter library

Comment: make sure you set the connection string in 'tnsnames.ora' correctly.

Comment: OracleClient depreciated by MS , You will ORacle data access libraries.Mention server details in tnanames.ora correcty as per default given format

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string looks like it is for MS Access. If you are trying to connect to Oracle, you may need to get the [Oracle library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

For a connection to Oracle example, look at this question: [Connect to Oracle without tnsname.ora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159298/net-connect-to-oracle).