# How to connect the oracle database with .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

How to connect the oracle database as a backend in asp.net (C#)?

what is the connection string for it?

when i was trying to connect i got the below error:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-12154 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190530/ora-12154-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net connect to Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159298/net-connect-to-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

The actual connection string depends on the parameters of your server (ip, instance name, credentials, etc).

Here's a site with several 'example' connection strings for oracle:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Oracle DB with .NET, best way is:

1. Install Oracle client
2. Configure tnsNames.ora
3. Reference .net project to Oracle.DataAccess.Dll (ODP.NET)
4. Create connection using `OracleConnection` object

I will not even go into other possibilities because this is golden standard for .net-Ora connectivity